# Access to PNRS of multiple Sabre PCCs from a single EPR (User id) token using Sabre SOAP API

Tags: sabre

I am creating a batch processing application to process PNRs from multiple PCCs using Sabre soap APIs. The application needs to access PNRs from different PCCs. The Sabre API documentation mentions that you can access PNRs created in a PCC only through the token created in that PCC. The problem is, I would not know the PCC of a PNR till I call the GetItinerary (ReservationRQ) on that PNR. I want to know if we can create an EPR in one PCC or IPCC that can have access to PNRs created in other PCCs so that I can maintain only one token in my application.

To be more specific,I am in process of writing following application logic

1. The users submit PNRs for processing (Amendments)
2. The front-end application queues the PNRs in a database table
3. The batch processing application picks up the PNR
4. Retrieves PNR details from Sabre using **GetReservationRQ**)
5. Batch application processes PNR as per the instructions provided by the user
6. Repeat steps 4 to 5 for each PNR

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Please let know if you need more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do can retrieve PNRs from different PCCs using one webservice credentials. An admin will be able to manage the user access to those PCCs setting the branch access from your IPCC.

Hope this helps.
P.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first branch those PCCs in order to access them. If this is the case you can use ContextChangeLLSRQ (Gui equivalent of AAA) to access and operate on other PCCs